# Can't make an Edit Text Object

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Android programing and I just can't find the reason why the application collaps every time I'm adding this line of code:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.myapplication.R.id.Client_Name; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

   EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(Client_Name);//The problmatic line
```

Other Views that I defined like that worked without problem

Here is the XMl:

```
<EditText 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:hint="Name" 
         android:layout_margin="16dp" 
         android:id="@+id/Client_Name" 
         android:inputType="text"/>
```

Comment: Use `R.id.Client_Name`

Comment: Your layout is not valid.

Comment: Are you trying to use`findViewById()` ignoring `Activity` life cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
findViewById(Client_Name);
```

to

```
findViewById(R.id.Client_Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are fetching wrong resource.Please read more.There are lots of tutorial online to learn.

```
EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Client_Name);//The problmatic line
```

In the latest android studio, you don't need to put your widget anymore.

```
EditText t = findViewById(R.id.Client_Name); // this will do the trick.
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(Client_Name);` inside onCreate() method.

And change `findViewById(Client_Name);` to `findViewById(R.id.Client_Name);`

Answer (score 0):

EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Client_Name);

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
findViewById(Client_Name);
```

to this one:

```
findViewById(R.id.Client_Name);
```